# Touching textinput slightly moves up screen react native

Tags: react-native

I am using `TextInput`but when I tap on the `TextInput` my screen slightly moves up.

How can I stop that from happening?

Here is the code for my `TextInput`

```
<TextInput style={{ height:45, borderBottomColor: '#FFFFFF', flex:1,}}
    placeholder="Email"
    keyboardType="email-address"
    underlineColorAndroid='black'
    onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}/>
```

Comment: Please add the code where you are using the `TextInput`, as from the current state of your question it is not clear as to what could be wrong.

Comment: are you using scrollView ?

Comment: no i am making login screen in which there are 2 textinputs and one button

Comment: can you add your whole screen(code) in question?

Comment: see this https://snack.expo.io/@jdgalani6297/Y2FsbS and run from there, Can't reproduce your issue. If you find the issue from this link then might be it is a device problem.

Answer (score 0):

**this is my code**

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={{width:'100%' , height: '100%' , flex:1}}>       
    <View style={{justifyContent: 'center',flexDirection:'row' , width:'100%', height:'10%' , alignItems: 'flex-start' ,backgroundColor: '#8e44ad' 
                      }}>
        <View style={{justifyContent: 'center' , width:'20%', height:'100%' , alignItems: 'flex-start' 
                      }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')}>
              <Image
                    source={{ uri: 'https://png.icons8.com/left-arrow/ultraviolet/50/3498db' }}
                    style={{ width: 30, height: 30  , marginLeft: 10}}
                  />
            </TouchableOpacity> 
        </View>              
         <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', width:'80%', height:'100%' , alignItems: 'flex-start'
                      }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20 , color: 'white' , marginLeft:80 ,fontWeight: 'bold'}}> Log In </Text>
        </View>                           
    </View>

    <View style={{width:'100%' , height: '100%', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        <View style={{width:'100%' , height: '40%' , justifyContent:'center' , alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <View style={{ borderBottomColor: '#F5FCFF',backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', borderBottomWidth: 1,
                        width:250,height:45,flexDirection: 'row',alignItems:'center',
                        margin: 10,}}>
            <Image  style={{width:30,
                         height:30,
                         marginLeft:15,
                         justifyContent: 'center'}}
                    source={{uri: 'https://png.icons8.com/message/ultraviolet/50/3498db'}}/>
            <TextInput style={{ height:45,
                                marginLeft:16,
                                borderBottomColor: '#FFFFFF',
                                flex:1,}}
                placeholder="Email"
                keyboardType="email-address"
                underlineColorAndroid='black'
                onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}/>
          </View>

          <View style={{ borderBottomColor: '#F5FCFF',backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',borderBottomWidth: 1,
                         width:250, height:45,flexDirection: 'row', alignItems:'center', margin: 10,}}>
            <Image style={{width:30,
                           height:30,
                           marginLeft:15,
                           justifyContent: 'center'}}
                 source={{uri: 'https://png.icons8.com/lock/ultraviolet/50/3498db'}}/>
            <TextInput style={{ height:45,
                                marginLeft:16,
                                borderBottomColor: '#FFFFFF',
                                flex:1,}}
                placeholder="password"
                keyboardType="email-address"
                underlineColorAndroid='black'
                onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}/>
          </View>
          <TouchableHighlight style={{height:45,flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',
                                    width:250, borderRadius:20, backgroundColor: "#8e44ad",marginTop: 20,}}
                             onPress={this.lgnButton}>
           <Text style={{color: 'white',fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
       </View>
       <View style={{width:'100%' , height: '60%', justifyContent:'flex-start' , alignItems: 'center'}}>
       <TouchableHighlight style={{ height:45,flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center',
                                    width:250, borderRadius:20, backgroundColor: "#8e44ad",marginTop: 20,}}
                             onPress={this.lgnButton}>
           <Text style={{color: 'white',fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Connect to facebook</Text>
         </TouchableHighlight>
       </View>
    </View>
  </View>
);
 }
  }
```